# ASP.NET Core Bluemix sample+VS 2015 update 3

Tags: asp.net, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, asp.net-core-1.0

I created a ASP.NET Core cloud foundry apps in IBM bluemix, which works fine. But when I download and try to build in VS 2015 update 3, I am not able to restore the packages hence getting the following error:

```
PATH=.\node_modules.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External;%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External\git
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe restore "C:\Users\c8\Downloads\HelloWorld(1).vs\restore.dg"
log : Restoring packages for C:\Users\c8\Downloads\HelloWorld(1)\src\dotnetstarter\project.json...
error: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine (>= 1.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0'.
log : Writing lock file to disk. Path: C:\Users\c8\Downloads\HelloWorld(1)\src\dotnetstarter\project.lock.json
Errors in C:\Users\c836774\Downloads\HelloWorld(1)\src\dotnetstarter\dotnetstarter.xproj
Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine (>= 1.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0'.
log : C:\Users\c8\Downloads\HelloWorld (1)\src\dotnetstarter\dotnetstarter.xproj
log : Restore failed in 966ms.
```

Update:

Added project.json config details:

```
{
    "buienter code hereldOptions": {
        "copyToOutput": {
            "include": [ "wwwroot" ]
        },
        "debugType": "portable",
        "emitEntryPoint": true,
        "preserveCompilationContext": true
    },

    "publishOptions": {
        "include": [ "wwwroot" ],
        "exclude": [ "**.user", "**.vspscc" ]
    },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.1"
    }
  },

    "frameworks": {
        "netcoreapp1.0": {
            "imports": [
                "portable-net45+wp80+win8+wpa81+dnxcore50"
            ]
        }
    },

    "scripts": { },

    "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

Comment: What version(s) of the .NET Core SDK do you have installed?  Also, please include at least the project.json file in the question itself so that future readers can see the code for the project in the question.

Comment: I am using .NET Core 1.0.1 core SDK

Comment: Are there any issues if you just run `dotnet restore` in the project folder from the command-line?

Answer (score 0):

I dint try that though, however changing my nuget.config to following helped me resolve the issue.

> ```
>    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <configuration>
>   <packageSources>
>     <!--To inherit the global NuGet package sources remove the <clear/> line below -->
>     <clear />
>     <add key="dotnet-core" value="https://dotnet.myget.org/F/dotnet-core/api/v3/index.json" />
>     <add key="api.nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
>   </packageSources>
> </configuration>
> ```